# ComponentDidMount vs ComponentWillMount?

Tags: reactjs

I have a question regarding when componentDidMount and when it fires, I'm new to working with react, and the examples for the documentation are vague. why is my component not firing?

```
var App = React.createClass({    
     getInitialState: function() {   
      var events = ['initial state has been called'];  
      return {   
       events: events   
      }    
     },         
     componentWillMount: function() {    
      return {    
       mount: this.state.events.push('componentWillMount has been called')    
      }    
     },    
     componentDidMount: function() {    
      return     
      console.log('mounted!');      
     },    
     render: function() {    
      var eventMap = this.state.events.map(function(event, i) {   
     return <li key={i}>{event}</li>;       
    })
      return (    
       <div>
        <ul>
         {eventMap}
        </ul>
       </div>
      )
     }
    })

    ReactDOM.render(
     <App />,
     document.getElementById('container')
    )
```

Comment: "why is my component not firing?" --- what does this exactly mean?

Comment: for example. When this code runs the output is a ul. Within the Ul is 'initialState has been called', 'componentWillMount has been called' but it does not console.log ('mounted!') I am curious as to why

Comment: It does not output `"mounted!"` because your `console.log` statement is after `return`. So `componentDidMount` function returns before `console.log`

Comment: I am confused as to why the componentDidMount isn't getting run.

Comment: Ah.. that is a fair point. But even without the console log, when I return an object with similar key, value to componentWillMount, it doesn't add that to the array

Comment: That's because `componentWillMount` is not supposed to return anything (and it is stated in the documentation explicitly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be asking why your `eventMap` does not contain the `li` with the string `'componentWillMount has been called'`. This is because you cannot `push` items to `this.state`. You have to call `this.setState` which will cause your `render` function to run again.

Also, it's not clear why you're returning an object with the key `mount`, as `componentWillMount` does not pass its result to anything.

```
componentWillMount: function() {    
  var events = this.state.events;
  events.push('a new value')    
  this.setState({ events: events }); // important!
}
```

You're probably also wonder why in your `componentDidMount` function the console message does not appear. This is because you cannot have a new line after return:

```
componentDidMount: function() {    
  return // magic semi-colon gets added here, nothing below will happen.
  console.log('mounted!');      
}
```

Do the right thing and put stuff you're returning on the same line (or use parens)

```
componentDidMount: function() {    
  return console.log('mounted!');
},
```

OR

```
componentDidMount: function() {    
  return (    
    console.log('mounted!');      
  )
}
```

But, as the rather rude @zerkms has pointed out, it makes no sense to return anything from this function.. this simply points out why your console.log was not firing.

I find these docs about component lifecycle to be pretty clear, so keep them open:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: Your suggestion for `componentDidMount` is weird: `return console.log('mounted!');` statement makes literally no sense.

Comment: That's not a suggestion, this is a correction to OP's code because he was wondering why the console.log was not firing.

Comment: It answers the OP's question, if you have a better answer post one.

Comment: Stating that someone's code is stupid is not being rude, but being honest. Nothing is as destructive as saying "good job" on something that is not.

Comment: It's rude to say that someone's code is stupid. Most humans make mistakes while learning. You can always say that the code is not right and show a better way to do it. That makes you a better professional and people listen to you, so you really make a difference.